# How to ovewrite addto.phtml

Tags: phtml

I want to overwrite file `design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml` in my custom module at path `design/frontend/default/default/mymodule/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`

Here I am ading layout file

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>wishlistnotification/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: have you closed <catalog_product_view>

Comment: Yes I have closed that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do an XML layout update (your code snippet) if you just want to override a template file. All you need to do is place the `phtml` file in the respective directory of your theme. So place a copy of

```
design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
```

to

```
design/frontend/*your_package*/*your_theme*/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
(not design/frontend/default/default/mymodule/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml)
```

That's it. Use XML layout updates if you want change how blocks are laid out or where they're shown (among other things).

Comment: I am using rwd theme of magento 1.9 and in that theme already have catalog/product/view/addto.phtml. So I must have to define that file in my module and then in respective hierarchy. So is there any way for this ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `rwd` theme directly, ideally. But if you're using that theme directly already, then you need to just edit the `rwd`'s `addto.phtml` file. You don't override template files with XML layout updates (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: You are right.But is there not any way to overwrite rwd theme's file in my module ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your module configuration, layout file is 'wishlistnotification.xml' and location 'app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/wishlistnotification.xml' . Put following code inside `<layout version="0.1.0">...</layout>`, layout tag

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.addto">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>wishlistnotification/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Clear Magento cache.

Comment: This is not working.Still 'rwd' theme's file is called  :(

Comment: Which theme you use? rwd or custom one. If rwd, then fallback could not search inside 'design/frontend/default/default/*'.

Comment: Yes I am using rwd theme.Please note that I only wanto change in phtml file.And as it is rwd theme there is already a file in catalog folder.So I must overrite that file in mymodule of rwd theme. And I am changing above changes in mymodule.xml at rwd theme.

Comment: can you show your config.xml?

Comment: <frontend><layout>
   <updates>
    <wishlistnotification>
     <file>wishlistnotification.xml</file>
    </wishlistnotification>
   </updates>
  </layout>
    </frontend>

Comment: Your layout file should be 'app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/wishlistnotification.xml' and template '/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/wishlistnotification/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml' .

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use layout updates for template files.  You can use theme fallbacks inside of Magento to override template files.

Create a folder `app/design/frontend/rwd/custom/`.

In that folder, create the structure `template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`

Inside your admin panel, go to `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes -> Templates` and set this to `custom`, which is the name of your overriding theme.

Now, Magento will look into this folder first for template files and fallback to  the original files if none are found in this folder.

Note: since you only changed the `Templates` section in system config, Magento will not look in here for any other theme assets or layout files.  It will only look in here for template files.